# What is a plugin for working with masks that also include optional characters and currency filter in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, currency, mask, currency-formatting, maskedinput

For example - vue-text-mask. But this plugin does not include check for optional symbols. 
**The way to define a mask in Text Mask is through an array.** [enter link description here](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/master/componentDocumentation.md#showmask).

I need to use masks for text fields. Vue-text-mask plugin - provides an array of masks, where 1 element of the array is a mask for 1 character of the entered string. But he does not check for optional characters, for example, for a string of the form: `^[0-9]{13,15}$`.

Comment: Try this plugin: https://github.com/Kocal/vue-numerals. I am only guessing (hard to understand your issue) - please add specific examples (Your Q is too general).

Comment: Hello, Ezra! I updated the question. I need a plugin for string values that does a check for optional characters, for example, for a string of the form: ^ [0-9] {13,15} $.

Comment: In general the best idea is to add small vue "not working" example (and give 2-3 output examples: i want this 1000 convert to 1,000€).